# Gmail API's history.list endpoint gives inaccurate data

Tags: gmail-api

I'm seeing the history list endpoint return incorrect data. When I add a label, the history API endpoint returns "labelsRemoved" and in fact returns the incorrect label id. Strangely, the information under payload['labelsRemoved']['message']['labelIds'] are correct.

Should we ignore the "labelsAdded" and "labelsRemoved" fields and just use the "messages" field instead?

Answer (score 1):

[Users.history: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list) have various properties per resource. `labelsAdded` and `labelsRemoved` are just lists if labels that were added/removed from the message. The main property `messages` will still contain the messages of the history record.

> List of messages changed in this history record. The fields for specific change types, such as messagesAdded may duplicate messages in this field. We recommend using the specific change-type fields instead of this.

Comment: The labels returned under labelsAdded or labelsRemoved are often (but not always) incorrect — I'm seeing the label 'INBOX' returned under labelsRemoved when all I did was *add* a *different* label to the message. At no point did I move to inbox or archive from inbox. 

Strangely, the labels returned under the res['labelsRemoved']['message']['labelIds'] are always correct. Just the calculated delta is not.